# Sending an email from c# windows application

Tags: c#

I have a windows c# application which is running on server, After it has been run everyday through task scheduler at certain time it generates a log file and now my issue can i send a  email  to my office id after it has finished running the application where there is no from address and needs to attach the log file with the email.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("eg@king.co.uk", "user@hotmail.com");
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Host = @"100.100.0.1";- fake host
        mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
        mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
        client.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: if you are using google, you need to EnableSsl = true and specify that port number. Be sure that the credentials are also given (i.e your username and password for the gmail account).

Comment: Your question is not clear. It sends mail on button click. When exactly you wants to send mail to your office ID

Comment: I am not using google i am using our own smtp address.

Comment: There's no questionmark anywhere in your question. What is your question?

Comment: @shruthi: What do you think `client.Host = "smtp.google.com";` means?

Comment: `client.Host = "smtp.google.com";` is this your own SMTP server? Are you from Google?

Comment: sorry guys ..I have edited my question..

Comment: You still are using Google's servers, so you must do as Ahmed instructed. By the way, you need to make your question explicitly clear (question marks go a long ways towards that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues in your code and question.

Your question says "how do I send an email to my office id". It's not clear what that means. Do you mean you have a company email address such as `shruti@mycompany.com` and you want to send an email to it?

There must be a from address. The address doesn't have to exist. For example, you would have a from address of `donotreply@mycompany.com`.

Your question includes the code for sending an email via Gmail's servers: `client.Host = "smtp.google.com";`. This makes everyone that is reading your question think you're trying to send an email via Google, which has specific requirements. If that's not the case, then update your question to be explicit. For example, if you're using a company hosted email server, you can use `smtp.mycompany.com`.

So if the question is really about how to attach a text file to your email, here's how you'd do that:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("donotreply@yourcompany.com", "user@hotmail.com");
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Port = 25;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Host = "smtp.mycompany.com";
    mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
    mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("log.txt"));
    client.Send(mail);  
    }
```

Notice I removed the `UseDefaultCredentials=false` because you didn't specify alternate credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format or name of the daily log message, you can use the following code after you create your MailMessage:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("you@yourcompany.com", "user@hotmail.com");
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("filepath.log"));
```